# run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the above error message trying to run this macro:
(Sorry about the size and messy state)
* <- means data removed for protection

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Button to select one client from "Search Result" and fill their information in "Client Details"

'On Error GoTo CloseDataPool

' Make sure the Client Number cell is empty

If Range("B2") = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please enter valid client number")
Exit Sub
End If

' Give row value to Client Number
Search_Result = 4 + Range("B2")
If Cells(Search_Result, 1) <> Range("B2") Then
MsgBox ("Please enter valid client number")
Exit Sub
End If

' Find client in Data Pool via Broker Reference, then find their row number

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\*\Dropbox\Shared Folder AT TH DH\Savant\*\Data Pool.xlsx"

Dim RC As Workbook
Dim DPW As Workbook
Dim DP As Worksheet
Dim SR As Worksheet
Dim CD As Worksheet
Dim PFDP As Worksheet
Set DPW = Workbooks("Data Pool")
Set DP = DPW.Worksheets("Data Pool")
Set RC = Workbooks("*")
Set SR = RC.Worksheets("Search Results")
Set CD = RC.Worksheets("Client Details")
Set PFDP = DPW.Worksheets("Prospect Fleet Data Pool")
Set PLDP = DPW.Worksheets("Prospect Liability Data Pool")

' Protect workbook and worksheets
CD.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
SR.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
DP.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
PFDP.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
PLDP.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
RC.Protect Password:="*", Structure:=True
DPW.Protect Password:="*", Structure:=True

Search_Result = SR.Range("B2") + 4
x = DP.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each Rowcheck In DP.Range("B2:B" & x)
If Rowcheck = SR.Range("B" & Search_Result) Then
y = Rowcheck.Row

CD.Range("E16") = DP.Cells(y, 1) 'Company Name
CD.Range("F38") = DP.Cells(y, 4) 'User added by
CD.Range("L38") = DP.Cells(y, 5) 'Date added on
End If
Next Rowcheck

Search_Result = CD.Range("F8")

Polcol = 2
Polrow = 45
x = PFDP.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each Rowcheck In PFDP.Range("A2:A" & x)
If Rowcheck = Search_Result Then
y = Rowcheck.Row
CD.Cells(Polrow, Polcol) = Polrow - 44
CD.Cells(Polrow, Polcol + 2) = PFDP.Cells(y, 3)
Polrow = Polrow + 1
End If
Next Rowcheck

x = PLDP.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each Rowcheck In PLDP.Range("A2:A" & x)
If Rowcheck = Search_Result Then
y = Rowcheck.Row
CD.Cells(Polrow, Polcol) = Polrow - 44
CD.Cells(Polrow, Polcol + 2) = PLDP.Cells(y, 3)
Polrow = Polrow + 1
End If
Next Rowcheck

'Add to history log
Set HLD = DPW.Worksheets("History Log")
HLD.Protect Password:="*", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
HLDR = HLD.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
HLD.Cells(HLDR, 1) = CD.Range("F8")

GoTo EndSub
CloseDataPool:
MsgBox ("An error has occurred")
EndSub:
Workbooks("Data Pool.xlsx").Save
Workbooks("Data Pool.xlsx").Close

End Sub
```

The line that's showing the error is:

```
Set HLD = DPW.Worksheets("History Log")
```

I've attempted to move this line near the start where I set the other Worksheets instead. I also move the protection line near the start as well. When I do this, the error reoccurs but on the next line down:

```
HLDR = HLD.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

I've also added a line just above to open the Data Pool workbook as whilst googling, I saw the error can occur by looking for items in a closed workbook. However, the error still persists.

I've looked around and I cannot find a solution. Can someone assist me in understanding this error?

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE], making sure that the error occurs, using only about 6-7 lines of code?

Comment: I've tried to shorten to 6-7 lines of code so that the macro is only working with the HLD variable. The problem does not reoccur.

Set DPW = etc.
Set HLD = Etc.
HLD.Protect...

This all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have posted too much code to get a tailored answer. Instead I will try to explain the problem in a more general way. Lines like these are the reason for your problem:

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\*\Dropbox\Shared Folder AT TH DH\Savant\*\Data Pool.xlsx"
...
...
Workbooks("Data Pool.xlsx").Save
```

Do like this instead:

```
Dim DataPool as Workbook
Set DataPool = Workbooks.Open("...\Data Pool.xlsx")
...
...
DataPool.Save
```

All other references to that object should be via the object variable, not the class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I apologise for the lengthy code. I've already removed half of the lines that do not impact the problem in any way. I'm not knowledgeable enough to reduce it further. I've also tested to make sure the problem re-occurs with the shortened code and it does.

Thank you for the advice on improving my code. Sadly, in this instance, the error remains.

Comment: Just to make sure - my advice above goes for all occurrences of that pattern. Also, rows like `Set DPW = Workbooks("Data Pool")` are also problematic. `Set DPW = Workbooks.Open("...\x.xlsx")` is better here

Comment: I've changed everything to the method you've suggested. It didn't work at first, but after moving things around it suddenly started working. I'm not entirely sure why, but I'll take it! thanks again for your advice.